# Need explanation of lambda behavior in example

Tags: python, lambda

I am looking in to python code which is part of reinforcement learning

```
LEFT, RIGHT = range(2)
pi = lambda s: {
    0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT
}[s]

for s in range(7):
    print(pi(s))

output:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

My question is what is [s] at lambda is present? what lambda behavior in this context. Is dictionary kept in list? If dictionary kept in list we have to access though list we have to put pi[0][s] in print right? Kindly explain

Comment: [s] is to access the value of the dictionary. like `dict[s]` which will give value as LEFT. s is the argument which goes from 0 to 6.

Comment: The question is "what is [s] at lambda is present?" but what does mean "present"?

Comment: `s` is the name of the argument being passed to the anonymous `lambda` function. The `[s]`  is referencing the value with that key in the dictionary.

Comment: That code does what should have been a list index operation in an extremely convoluted way. `pi = [LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT]` ... `print(pi[s])` or `for p in pi: print(p)`.

Comment: Here pi is a function defined with the lambda notation. But the function is strange as it always returns 0 if parameter is 0,1,2,3,4,5 or 6. Goal is not clear here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pi = lambda s: {
    0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT
}[s]
```

is nothing more than

```
def pi(s):
    return {0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT}[s]
```

where

```
{0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT}[s]
```

is getting in a dict (here `{0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT}`) the attribute for the key `s`.
So `{0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT}[1]` gives `LEFT` because `LEFT` is the attribute for key `1`.

Comment: or just simply `return [LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT, LEFT][s]` (or use a tuple), there is no point in using a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The above code defines this dictionary:

```
dict = {
    0:LEFT, 1:LEFT, 2:LEFT, 3:LEFT, 4:LEFT, 5:LEFT, 6:LEFT
}
```

or alternatively (`left = 0`):

```
dict = {
    0:0, 1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0
}
```

The `pi` lambda returns `dict[s]` where `s` is the `key` in dictionary.
So calling `pi(s)` is equal to returning `dict[s]` for key = `s`.